# Fulton and Harris: Exercise 1.3 in section 1.1

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

This is exercise 1.3 on page 5 of Fulton and Harris *Representation Theory: A First Course*.

**Exercise**: Let $G$ be a finite group, let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space and let $\rho: G\to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be a representation of $G$. Suppose that for all $g$ in $G$, the determinant of $\rho(g)$ is $1$ (i.e., $\rho: G\to \mathrm{SL}(V)$). Show that the spaces $\land^kV$ and $\land^{n-k}(V^*)$ are isomorphic as representations of $G$. *Hint*: The hypotheses ensure that $\land^nV$ is trivial, and the bilinear map $\land^kV\otimes \land^{n-k}V\to \land^nV = \mathbb C$ is a perfect pairing, i.e., it makes each space the dual of the other, c.f. Sect. B.3.

I have some ideas but no solution. Since $V$ is $n$-dimensional, $\land^n V$ is $1$-dimensional, so I suppose we can identify it with $\mathbb C$. Each $g$ in $G$ acts on $\mathbb C$ by a nonzero scalar, but I don't know how to use $\det \rho(g) = 1$ to show that this scalar must be $1$. Maybe I can identify $\rho(g)$ with its vector of columns in $V^{\oplus n}$ and use the fact that $\det$ is multilinear alternating?

The map $\land^kV\otimes \land^{n-k}V\to \land^nV$ looks like evaluation. If I could figure out the appropriate coevaluation $\mathbb C\to \land^{n-k}V\otimes\land^kV$, I could show that $\land^kV$ and $\land^{n-k}V$ are dual and thus isomorphic as vector spaces (since they are finite-dim). In that case $\land^{n-k}(V^*)\cong (\land^{n-k}V)^*\cong \land^kV$, but I would still have to show that this isomorphism respects $G$.

Comment: Hint: If $\wedge^nV$ is $1$-dimensional, then $\rho(g)\in GL_{\mathbb{C}}(1)$ (what is $GL_{\mathbb{C}}(1)$ in less unusual notation?) and what does it mean that an element of $GL(1)$ has determinant $1$?

Comment: Hi Michael- $\mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb C}(1) = \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C^\times$, yes? The determinant $\mathbb C^\times\to \mathbb C$ is the identity map (or inclusion, I suppose). Is there a commutative diagram I can draw using naturality of $\det$ that shows that $\rho(g)$ and the corresponding $\big(\rho(g)\big)^\prime$ in $\mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb C}(1)$ have the same determinant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) First, you have an isomorphism $\bigwedge^nV\otimes\left(\bigwedge^k V\right)^*\cong\bigwedge^{n-k}V$ which is given by $(w_1\wedge\dots\wedge w_n)\otimes \omega\mapsto\omega(w_1\wedge\dots\wedge w_k)\cdot w_{k+1}\wedge\dots\wedge w_n$ which is an element of $\bigwedge^{n-k}V$.

(2) Second, $G$ acts on $\bigwedge^nV$ trivially since the determinants are all $1$, so this is a copy of the trivial representation $\mathbb C$.

(3) So you go back to point 1 and what you have is actually $G$-linear (just check it, basically from the definition of how $G$ acts on exterior products) and so you get a sequence of $G$-isomorphisms $$\left(\bigwedge^kV\right)^*=\left(\bigwedge^kV\right)^*\otimes\mathbb C\cong\left(\bigwedge^kV\right)^*\otimes\bigwedge^nV\cong\bigwedge^{n-k}V.$$

You can then use a remark preceding the exercise to finish.

Comment: Hello rmhism,
(1) I don't understand the notation "u(⋅)=w(ω1,…,ωk,⋅)." I see the bijection of bases: 
$v_{i_1}^*\land v^*_{i_2}^*\land\cdots \land v^*_{i_{n-k}}\mapsto v_{j_1}\land\cdots v_{j_k}$ where $j_1, \ldots, j_k$ are the indices that do not appear in $i_1, \ldots, i_{n-k}$. Is this related to the map you give?

(2) It is given that the determinant of $\rho(g)$ in $GL(V)$ is 1 for all $g$. From this, how do you determine that the determinant of $g$ in $GL(\land^nV)$ is also 1?

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw this... I hope you figured it out. 1) I've edited the comment to hopefully make it clearer. What I had before may have been wrong. 2) This is one of the definitions of determinant, using wedge products.

Comment: The isomorphism in (1) isn't surjective (onto $\bigwedge^{n-k} V$); there's only one basis vector, say $e_1 \wedge \dots e_n$ in $\bigwedge^{n} V$ to consider, so the image only contains elements proportional to $e_{k+1} \wedge e_n$, if we define it this way. Otherwise, the map isn't well-defined, as the components in the wedge product can be reordered (with possibly a sign), so it's not meaningful to act with $\omega$ on the first $k$ components.